# Unable to generate list of XTS objects using apply in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, xts, shiny-reactivity

I have the following R-Shiny Module which tries to take the excel file path, sheet name and data range upon click of a button.

The excel will always contain "Date" as the first column.

I then read the inputs using read_excel() to form a dataframe and then try to convert the data frame into an XTS object by extracting the first column of the dataframe as the datevector. (in lines 117 to 123).

This is part of the relevant code

```
 
      XLdata.list <- apply(XLdata.matrix, MARGIN=1, function(x) {temp.tibble <- (read_excel(path =x[2], sheet =x[3], range = x[4], col_names=TRUE, trim_ws=TRUE))
                                                                 temp.df <- as.data.frame(temp.tibble) %>% filter_all(any_vars(complete.cases(.)))
                                                                 temp.dv <- temp.df[,"Date"]
                                                                 temp.matrix <- temp.df %>% dplyr::select(-c("Date"))
                                                                 temp.xts <- xts(temp.matrix, order.by = as.Date(temp.dv))
                                                                 
                                                                 return(temp.df)} ) # if i replace temp.df with temp.xts, this doesnt work.
```

However, i am facing a strange trouble. I am able to return the "dataframe object" correctly BUT unable to return the "XTS" object.

The same code to convert dataframe into XTS works outside of the shiny environment, but within the shiny environment, I am getting an error which says

```
Warning: Error in array: length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

if I replace the line 123 with `return(temp.df)` instead of `return(temp.xts)`, this works fine.

Please help!!

**Full code**

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)


#----
#Import Excel Data Module
#On User Click, UI for Excel path, sheet and range will be generated
#This will ask for Excel File Path, Sheet Name and Data Range
#This will then convert these details into File Name based on click 
#This module will give the list of dataframes as Output.  The checkbox button is now used. 
#----



#----
#UI for import Excel Data
#----
library(shiny)

Import.Excel.Data.UI <- function(id){
  
   ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("AddExcelDataButton"), label = HTML("Click Here to Add Excel Data <br/> There should a 'Date' Column")),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("XLlist"))
  )
  
}




Import.Excel.Data.Server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$AddExcelDataButton,
                
                 insertUI(selector=paste0("#",ns("AddExcelDataButton")),
                          multiple=TRUE,
                          where = "afterEnd",
                          
                          ui = tags$hr(
                            tags$div(fileInput(inputId = ns(paste0("ExcelFile",input$AddExcelDataButton)),
                                         label = paste0("Path for File",input$AddExcelDataButton),
                                         multiple  = FALSE),
                                     style = "display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"
                                     ),#end of tags$div
                          
                             tags$div(textInput(inputId = ns(paste0("ExcelSheetName",input$AddExcelDataButton)),
                                      label = paste0("Excel Sheet Name",input$AddExcelDataButton),
                                      value = "AllTickers"),
                                      style = "display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"
                                      ),#end of tags$div
                            
                            tags$div(textInput(inputId = ns(paste0("ExcelSheetRange",input$AddExcelDataButton)),
                                               label = paste0("Excel Sheet Range", input$AddExcelDataButton),
                                               value = "M7:AL10000"),
                                     style = "display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"
                            ),#end of tags$div
                            
                            
                            tags$div(checkboxInput(inputId = ns(paste0("ExcelFileCheck",input$AddExcelDataButton)),
                                               label = paste0("Check to Use File", input$AddExcelDataButton),
                                               value = TRUE),
                                     style = "display:inline-block;"
                            ),#end of tags$div
                            
                            tags$div(textInput(inputId = ns(paste0("ExcelDataName",input$AddExcelDataButton)),
                                                   label = paste0("Data Name", input$AddExcelDataButton,"(make sure no repeat names)"),
                                                   placeholder = "Default name is filename. make sure there is no repeat. No checks"),
                                     style = "display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"
                            )#end of tags$div
                 
                 
                            
                            
                 )#end of tags$hr  
                 
                 )#end of insertUI
    )#end of observeEvent
    
   
    
    XLdata <- reactive({
      req(input[[paste0("ExcelFile",input$AddExcelDataButton)]]) ###added as per suggestion from stackoverflow. may not be necessary. 
      for (i in 1: input$AddExcelDataButton)
      {
       temp.filename <- input[[paste0("ExcelFile",i)]]$name
       temp.filepath <- input[[paste0("ExcelFile",i)]]$datapath
       temp.sheetname <- input[[paste0("ExcelSheetName",i)]]
       temp.sheetrange <- input[[paste0("ExcelSheetRange",i)]]
       temp.filecheck <- input[[paste0("ExcelFileCheck",i)]]
       ifelse(input[[paste0("ExcelDataName",i)]]=="", temp.dataname <- input[[paste0("ExcelFile",i)]]$name, temp.dataname <-input[[paste0("ExcelDataName",i)]]  )
       row.temp <- cbind(temp.filename, temp.filepath, temp.sheetname, temp.sheetrange, temp.filecheck, temp.dataname)
        
        
        
        ifelse(i<=1,
              {
                XLdata.matrix <- row.temp
              },#end of if condition in ifelse i<=1
              {
                XLdata.matrix <- rbind(XLdata.matrix, row.temp)
              } #end of else in ifelse i<=1
              )#end of ifelse brackets
        
      }#end of for-loop
      
   
      XLdata.matrix <- as.data.frame(XLdata.matrix)
      
      
      
      XLdata.list <- apply(XLdata.matrix, MARGIN=1, function(x) {temp.tibble <- (read_excel(path =x[2], sheet =x[3], range = x[4], col_names=TRUE, trim_ws=TRUE))
                                                                 temp.df <- as.data.frame(temp.tibble) %>% filter_all(any_vars(complete.cases(.)))
                                                                 temp.dv <- temp.df[,"Date"]
                                                                 temp.matrix <- temp.df %>% dplyr::select(-c("Date"))
                                                                 temp.xts <- xts(temp.matrix, order.by = as.Date(temp.dv))
                                                                 
                                                                 return(temp.xts)} ) # removes only rows with ALL NA's including the DATE column. 
      
      names(XLdata.list) <- XLdata.matrix$temp.dataname
        
      XLdata.list
      
      
    })#end of reactive for XLdata
    
    output$XLlist <- renderPrint(glimpse(XLdata()))
    return(XLdata)  ## added based on the suggestion from stackoverflow. this is necessary.  No double brackets for XLdata() -- but why? 

  })#end of module server
}



#----BELOW CODE IS TO TEST  THE MODULE ON ITS OWN-------
Import.Excel.Data.App <- function(){
  ui <- fluidPage(
   Import.Excel.Data.UI("File1"),
   verbatimTextOutput("XLdata.list.output")




  )


  server <- function(input, output, session){
    XLdata.list <- Import.Excel.Data.Server("File1")
    output$XLdata.list.output <- renderPrint(XLdata.list())


  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

Import.Excel.Data.App()
```

Comment: That does not look like a problem with Shiny. Could you remove all the unnecessary Shiny parts to replicate the issue? The more to the point questions are asked the more likely they attract good answers. With all that extra code it is hard to identify what is relevant and what isn't.

Comment: I might be missing something in my code, which I am unable to figure out, but the code to convert dataframe to XTS object works fine outside of the shiny environment actually.

Comment: i added highlighted the part of the code where I think is the mistake. I kept the full code below in case anyone wants to replicate the problem as the part code is unable to replicate the problem as it is.